# Converting delimiter from semicolon to comma in a CSV?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I have a simple scenario where I am changing the delimiter in a CSV from `;` (semicolon) to `,` (comma). Below is the code

Code:

```
import csv
semicolonin = csv.reader(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv", delimiter=';')
commaout = csv.writer(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv", delimiter=',')
for row in semicolonin:
    commaout.writerow(row)
```

But I receive an error. Am I missing something?

```
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

while executing line `commaout = csv.writer(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv", delimiter=',')`.

Comment: You passed a file path instead of a file object. `csv.reader(open(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv"), delimiter=';')`

Comment: You want to use a different filename for output than input. Unless losing all the data is your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rewriting your whole CSV file, you can use pandas library.

```py
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv("C:\pyscripts\1.csv")
f.to_csv("C:\pyscripts\1.csv", sep=";")
```

As you can see, it allows you to read CSV file and choose your separator with the `sep='<your_separator>'` option, will it be a comma, a semi-colon or the separator of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a file object to the writer method, like so:

```
import csv
with open(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv") as in_file, open(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv", 'w') as out_file:
    semicolonin = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=';')
    commaout = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in semicolonin:
        commaout.writerow(row)
```

Comment: above code outputs only the path name in the csv file & nothing else.

Comment: Right, same problem as with the writer. you have to give the file object to  csv.reader and not just the path.

Comment: So what is the Solution here ?

Comment: the code above reads in the file correctly.  "open(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv") as in_file" opens a second file object for reading the input file

Comment: so for out_file I need to give a different file name?

Comment: So uh...this worked for me, but it put a blank row between each row lol

Comment: Note that you may want to use both parameters newline='' and encoding="utf-8" in above second "open". Aka : open(r"C:\pyscripts\1.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8").
*  newline is to avoid blank lines in output * encoding is to choose encoding.